# Is there any way by which we can add limit data to be log using winston

Tags: logging, error-logging, winston

We want to limit on size of data to be logged using [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) library.

For example : winston provides a function as follows

`logger.info('message', {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})`

So in above case, if size of message & json data goes above 10kb or 20kb, it should ignore that log with warning, saying log data above accepted storage limit or something.

Is there any such option present in winston library.

We can make changes in existing library directly or we can write a wrapper before library that will check volume of data & if it is less than 10/20kb, then only provide it to winston, but we don't want that. We need if there is any option or configuration present in winston which will do validation for us.